# Split horizon based on IP returned by upstream DNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, split-dns

In a split horizon setup, I'd like to use a DNS server running in the local network, to resolve DNS queries to the local IP of a server. I know about the possibility to setup a DNS server in a way that it always returns a local IP (different from the upstream DNS) for a certain hostname. However, I don't like to have the hassle of keeping a current list of all hostnames pointing to the server whose DNS I'd like to split.

However, I'd like to set this up in a way, that the local DNS does interfere with the DNS response based on the IP returned by the external DNS. (If returned IP by upstream DNS matches, return local IP - instead of IF query hostname matches, return local IP).

Is this possible with any current DNS software?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  F5 makes a product that can "interfere" with DNS based on requests.  It is part of the iRule interpreter on the Big-IP product line.

https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/need-an-irule-to-forward-dns-requests-based-on-fqdn

Comment: Thank you, your comment is helpful, but I'd prefer a FOSS solution to this.